# Enzyme – test event handler function who needs an arbitrary `target` property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, preact

Disclaimer: I'm using **Preact** as a lib and `enzyme-adapter-preact-pure` as the Enzyme's adapter.

---

I wrote the following function:

```
function handleInputChange(e) {
  const target = e.target,
    value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  this.setState({ [target.name]: value });
}
```

This function is **standalone** and it's meant to be used inside React's 
Component instances like that:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: null
    };

    this.handleInputChange = handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <input name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />;
  }
}
```

This way I don't need to reimplement it on every component that needs to handle input changes.

### The problem:

As I rely on `event.target` and it's properties, I don't know how to test it with Enzyme, because I can't set the `target` and those properties as I wish:

```
// Test file
// Consider `wrapper` as an instance of `App` shown above, mounted with Enzyme's `mount` function.

test('it changes the correspondent state key when input is changed', () => {
  wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'foo', name: 'name' } });
  expect(wrapper.state('name')).toEqual('foo');
});
```

Trying this is throwing an error: `TypeError: Cannot set property target of [object Event] which has only a getter at Function.assign (<anonymous>)`

Comment: i see only one problem with this code is you are not passing name in target which would cause different error. expected null to be foo. there is something else in your code which is causing this error.

Comment: I update `wrapper.find("input").simulate('change', {target: {value: 'foo', name: 'name'}});` and test are passed for me.

Comment: Well, I think I missed an important information: I'm using **Preact**, not React. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are relying on more than just `target.value` you also need to pass appropriate mock that covers all your bases.

Below code should resolve it.

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {
  target: {
    value: 'foo',
    name: 'name',
    checked: true,
    type: 'checkbox'
  }
});

// OR

// In this case there will be no checkbox found and this it wont look for checked value present or not
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {
  target: {
    value: 'foo',
    name: 'name'
  }
});
```

Comment: not passing correct data should not throw error mentioned in question. i tried same code i and got error saying expected null to be foo.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but error seems to be triggered from this OP's statement: `this.setState({ [target.name]: value });`